# How to get one set of data from a SQL query from multiple table?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

My table structure is

```sql
TABLE_1
|------|------|-------|
|  ID  | NAME | PHONE | = 1 ROW
|------|------|-------|
TABLE_2
|------|------------|----------|
|  ID  | TABLE_1_ID | CATEGORY | = 5 ROW
|------|------------|----------|
TABLE_3
|------|------------|----------|
|  ID  | TABLE_1_ID | ADDRESS  | = 3 ROW
|------|------------|----------|
```

I am working with the above table. But my result generating 1 row but in the CATEGORY cell its displaying 5 CATEGORY but it's repeating 3 times and in the ADDRESS cell the 3 addresses repeating 5 times, like below -

```sql
RESULT
|----|------|-------|----------------------------|------------------|
|    |      |       |                            | (ADR1,ADR2,ADR3) |
|    |      |       | (CAT1,CAT2,CAT3,CAT4,CAT5) | (ADR1,ADR2,ADR3) |
| ID | NAME | PHONE | (CAT1,CAT2,CAT3,CAT4,CAT5) | (ADR1,ADR2,ADR3) |
|    |      |       | (CAT1,CAT2,CAT3,CAT4,CAT5) | (ADR1,ADR2,ADR3) |
|    |      |       |                            | (ADR1,ADR2,ADR3) |
|----|------|-------|----------------------------|------------------|
```

My PHP+SQL is

```php
$db = new Database;
$getData = "SELECT a.name, a.phone, b.category, c.address
FROM table_1 a JOIN table_2 b JOIN table_3 c
WHERE a.id = b.table_1_id AND a.id = c.table_1_id
ORDER BY a.id ASC";
$execute = $db->select($getData);
$result        = [];
$currentParent = false;
$data          = null;
foreach ($execute as $row) {
    if ($currentParent != $row['id']) {
        if($data != null){ 
            $result[]= $data;
        }
        $data = [
            'name'     => $row['name'],
            'phone'    => $row['phone'],
            'category' => '',
            'address'  => ''
        ];
        $currentParent = $row['id'];
    }
    $data['category'] = empty($data['category']) ? $row['category'] : $data['category'] .", ". $row['category'];
    $data['address']  = empty($data['address'])  ? $row['address']  : $data['address']  .", ". $row['address'];
}
$result[]= $data;
echo json_encode($result);
```

Now the question is, How am I going to achieve 1 set of 5 category and 1 set of 3 address in my result. Thanks in advance.

## My Data

```sql
TABLE_1 DATA
|------|------|-------|
|  ID  | NAME | PHONE |
|------|------|-------|
|  1   | JON  | 123   |
|------|------|-------|
TABLE_2 DATA
|------|------------|----------|
|  ID  | TABLE_1_ID | CATEGORY |
|------|------------|----------|
|  1   |      1     |   CAT1   |
|------|------------|----------|
|  2   |      1     |   CAT2   |
|------|------------|----------|
|  3   |      1     |   CAT3   |
|------|------------|----------|
|  4   |      1     |   CAT4   |
|------|------------|----------|
|  5   |      1     |   CAT5   |
|------|------------|----------|
TABLE_3 DATA
|------|------------|----------|
|  ID  | TABLE_1_ID | ADDRESS  |
|------|------------|----------|
|   1  |      1     |   ADR1   |
|------|------------|----------|
|   2  |      1     |   ADR2   |
|------|------------|----------|
|   3  |      1     |   ADR3   |
|------|------------|----------|
```

My new query with `GROUP_CONCAT`

```sql
SELECT a.id, a.name, a.phone, 
 GROUP_CONCAT(b.category ORDER BY b.category SEPARATOR ',') category,
 GROUP_CONCAT(c.address ORDER BY c.address SEPARATOR ',') address
    FROM table_1 a INNER JOIN table_2 b ON (a.id = b.table_1_id) INNER JOIN table_3 c ON (a.id = c.table_1_id)
    GROUP BY a.id, a.name, a.phone
```

This query also generating same result and my PHP is same as above.

Comment: I'm not sure what output you're expecting

Comment: If you are using joins(and you should) you should also use them properly by including the ON clauses..

Comment: I updated my question with my table data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query involves multiple joins that is why you are getting multiple rows for category and address, In your application code you can display set of category and address once by tweaking your existing logic.

Maintain temporary variables of category and address`($categories,$addresses)` for each item of `table_1` and use `in_array()` to make sure no duplicate address and categories are added to your temporary variables `$categories & $addresses` and inside loop when your iteration changes from one item to different one then create a comma separated string of previously collected categories and addresses

```
$currentParent = false;
$data          = null;
$categories =$addresses = [];
foreach ($execute as $row) {
    if ($currentParent != $row['id']) {
        if($data != null){ 
            $data['category'] = implode (", ", $categories);
            $data['address'] = implode (", ", $addresses);
            $result[]= $data;
            $categories =$addresses = [];
        }
        $data = [
            'name'     => $row['name'],
            'phone'    => $row['phone'],
            'category' => '',
            'address'  => ''
        ];
        $currentParent = $row['id'];
    }
    if (in_array($row['category'], $categories) === false) {
        array_push($categories, $row['category']);
    }
    if (in_array($row['address'], $addresses) === false) {
        array_push($addresses, $row['address']);
    }
}

$data['category'] = implode (", ", $categories); // for last item
$data['address'] = implode (", ", $addresses); // for last item
$result[]= $data;
echo json_encode($result);
```

Comment: This code not displaying any data in the category and address field. but its displaying name and phone fields.

Comment: @Bearded my bad `array_push` was using `$data` instead of `$row`

Comment: Its working perfectly. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 4):

I will try to answer using SQL only.

Use group_concat with distinct,

```
select t.id,name,phone,
 group_concat(distinct a.addr separator ',') as address,
 group_concat(distinct c.cat separator ',') as category
  from table1 t
  left join address a 
    on t.id = a.refid
  left join category c
    on t.id = c.refid
  group by t.id,name, phone
```

**OR**

As inline column,

```
select t.id,name,phone,
 (select group_concat(a.addr separator ',')
    from address a 
   where a.refid = t.id) as address,
 (select group_concat(c.cat separator ',') 
    from category c
   where c.refid = t.id) as category
  from table1 t
```

Reference [Db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=67fed41e1f474f6a23eda27fab26bcea)

Comment: Group concat has character limit restriction, do mention this in your answer and how this limit can be increased

Comment: Thanks for the hint but it is not part of the question and I don't want to put more information at this time.

Comment: As it will result in loss of information if addresses length exceeds a default limit of group concat

Comment: Above query(first one) is working and it's showing 1 sets of category and 1 sets of address.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have not porvided the complete data I can only suggest that you can make use of GROUP_CONCAT funtion in MYSQL.

So your query will be something like this.

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=71e9e02f4ff39669871d2de63172afe8)

```
    SELECT a.id, a.name, a.phone, 
 GROUP_CONCAT( distinct b.cat ORDER BY b.cat SEPARATOR ',') category,
 GROUP_CONCAT(distinct c.addr ORDER BY c.addr SEPARATOR ',') address
    FROM table1 a INNER JOIN category b ON (a.id = b.refid) INNER JOIN address c ON (a.id = c.refid )
    GROUP BY a.id, a.name, a.phone;
```

Comment: Can you share your query and sample data for all three tables.

Comment: I have updated my answer based on the data provided and added demo as well. Please check.

Comment: the result of your query is not accurate. You have to use `distinct` inside `group_concat` for accurate result. See @Sujitmohanty30 answer please.

Comment: Updated it based on your comments.