# PHP MYSQL CONCAT

Tags: php, mysql, concatenation, group-concat

I'm doing some voluntary work for a group of local businesses delivering food to vulnerable people during COVID.

An example of an order:

```
Order No |  Customer Name | Address | Quantity | Item Name | Notes
===================================================
 #1234     |     Freda Smith      |3 High St   |      1     |   Loaf Bread  | Wholemeal 
 #1234     |     Freda Smith      |3 High St   |      2     |   500ml Milk  | Skimmed
 #1234     |     Freda Smith      |3 High St   |      1     |   Tea         | Eng. Breakfast
```

I need to print all the details of order No #1234 onto one ticket, like this:

```
#1234, Freda Smith, 3 High St
     
1 X Loaf Bread, Wholemeal   
2 X 500ml Milk, skimmed  
1 X Tea, Eng. Breakfast
```

I have toyed with `CONCAT` and `CONCAT_GROUP` and have tried to figure out by separating the `SELECT` from the HTML formatting but can't get what I need. I'm close but no cigar!

EDIT:

```
SELECT IS:             $sql =    "SELECT id,
                       Order_Number, 
                       Full_Name,
                       Address,
                       Time_To_Deliver,
                CONCAT(Quantity, Item_Name, Notes)
                FROM orders
                CONCAT_GROUP BY Order_Number";
                    
            $users = $mysqli->query($sql);
            while($user = $users->fetch_assoc()){
```

Comment: Do you have some code which prints a ticket (or even a loop which loops over the tickets to print)

Comment: you don't need concat.  you need to iterate over the items in the order and render the items in the ticket.  Customer name and address shouldn't be duplicated in each order item record - I think tht's what's throwing you off.

Comment: I'm looping through but can only get either a separate row for each item, or only one row containing the first item.

Comment: You could use `group_concat` then explode on the `,` (or parse as CSV) but it'll be the same as iterating over the result object and just outputting the order meta data once (if id is the same don't output order info, just quantity, notes, and name).

Comment: Can you upload your PHP code?

Comment: I can loop over everything fine but can't figure out how to then output the order number once, name once, address once and still have the three items and three notes attached to that order number. Either I have three of every row or one!

Comment: SELECT IS:             $sql =    "SELECT id,
                       Order_Number, 
                       Full_Name,
                       Address,
                       Time_To_Deliver,
                CONCAT(Quantity, Item_Name, Notes)
                FROM orders
                CONCAT_GROUP BY Order_Number";
                    
            $users = $mysqli->query($sql);
            while($user = $users->fetch_assoc()){

Comment: added code blocks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current design has redundant data you should [normalize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) your database structure by maintaining separate table for order & order items further more you can add a customer table also.

As per your current design you can loop through all of the rows and conditionally showing each order no. only once.

```
select id,
    order_number,
    full_name,
    address,
    time_to_deliver,
    quantity,
    item_name,
    notes
from orders
order by order_number asc
```

Here `order by` clause is important so that you will get an ordered list of items for each order. Once you have all the results from query you can loop through your data as

```
$currentParent = false;
while ($orderItem = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
   if ($currentParent != $orderItem['order_number']) {
        // display common detail of each order here
        echo '<h1>' . $orderItem['order_number'] .' '. $orderItem['full_name'] .' '. $orderItem['address']'</h1>';
        $currentParent = $orderItem['order_number'];
    }
    echo '<p>' . $orderItem['quantity'] .' '. $orderItem['item_name'] . ' '. $orderItem['notes'] .'</p>'; // here list rest of the information of order iterms 
    ...     
}
```

Generated markup will be like

```
<h1>#1234, Freda Smith, 3 High St</h1>
    <p>1 X Loaf Bread, Wholemeal</p>
    <p>2 X 500ml Milk, skimmed </p>
<h1>#1235, Freda Smith, 3 High St</h1>
    <p>1 X Tea, Eng. Breakfast</p>
//....
```

Although you can use aggregation with `group_concat` (see [`Query for post and tags in same query`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31766576/query-for-post-and-tags-in-same-query/31824955#31824955)) directly on database level but it has limitations of character limit which can be adjusted but not a good approach to follow when you can handle this type of situation at application layer

Comment: Amazing, thank you! I'm off delivering now but will go through your advice as soon as I can. I really appreciate it, thank you!

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much! You've helped make life a lot easier for some very vulnerable people!